# datatables js speed up?

Tags: jquery, datatables

i am loading more than 10000 records in a datatables in client side, it takes more time for binding all records so i did the following two steps

```
1. first loaded 100 records in datatables using fnAddData() and fnDraw().
2. remaining records loaded to datatables in settimeout function.
```

Time taken to load first 100 records is very speed, Eventhough i loaded rest records using settimeout function i face the following issues

```
 Page goes to not responding until the records bind to datatables
```

Any idea how to solve the page not responding issue, i need to load data quickly either full records at a time or first some records later rest using settimeout.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using the [server-side options](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) that DataTables provides.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "../server_side/scripts/server_processing.php"
    } );
} );
```

Comment: what exactly server side options will do

Comment: With server-side processing enabled, all paging, searching, ordering actions that DataTables performs are handed off to a server where an SQL engine (or similar) can perform these actions on the large data set.

Comment: but i am loading data fully in client side so is serverside processing will work

Answer (score 0):

Consider using **pagination**. This will only render X number of records into the DOM at once and allow you iterate over pages to view the remaining records. Since 99% of your records won't need to be rendered into the DOM to start, this should speed up the loading speed.

```html
$('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'lrtip',
    paging: true,
    pageLength: 50,
});
```